# Strange sound when setting custom notification sound Android

Tags: android

I've setted the following code to play a custom MP3 sound:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://nl.myapp.myappver/" + R.raw.mysound);
```

However on my HTC debug phone the sound doesn't play it plays a very weird tone.
It's not the default tone because that sounds different.
Logs

```
10-25 20:48:00.578: V/MediaPlayer(31528): setDataSource(android.resource://nl.myapp.myappver/2130968576)
10-25 20:48:00.578: V/MediaPlayerService(31483): setDataSource(android.resource://nl.myapp.myappver/2130968576)
10-25 20:48:00.578: V/MediaPlayerService(31483): getPlayerTypeFromMAP(android.resource://nl.myapp.myappver/2130968576): PLAYERS_MAP[18].playertype (UNKNOWN player_type code)0
10-25 20:48:00.578: I/AwesomePlayer(31483): setDataSource_l('android.resource://nl.myapp.myappver/2130968576')
10-25 20:48:02.380: D/HfmMessageReceiver(15434): receive ACTION_NOTIFICATION_SOUND_COMPLETE, pkg= nl.myapp.myappver, id= 920
```

What's the reason for my phone to play a different tone?
The sound file is an MP3 file of +/- 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I had to save the file as .ogg instead of .mp3 now the sound plays fine!